# How to login in Django Rest Auth using username or email

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

In my django project, I am using django rest auth for api authentication. The default is to use username and password for login. I can also use email and password. But I want my user to have the option of either using email or username and password for login authentication; which I believe is more user friendly.
How do I do this in django rest auth?